# Ajax is not working. i need to refresh half of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

```
<html>

    <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com" >
        <b>Enter Text</b><input type="text" id="pv2" name="pv2"/>
        <input type="button" value="Report Generation" class="button" onclick="samepage()"/>
   </form>
    <script src="http://www.jquery4u.com/function-demos/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jquery4u.com/scripts/function-demos-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Function samepage()
{
Var text =Document.getElementById("pv2").value;
Var Data= text;
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://www.google.com" // form action url
      data: Data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(output)
      {
Document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= output;
      }     
      });
}
This dynamic div
</script>
<div id="output" style="border:1px solid;width:1000px;height:500px;">
</div>
</html>
```

it need to load the one website along with theinput data given by the user.for the testing purpose i had used the google.com.i need the google.com to get loaded in the div tag .

In the above It is not loading ....

Comment: `Function != function && Document != document && Var != var`

Comment: can you tell me in detail

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
function samepage()
{
   var text =document.getElementById("pv2").value;
   var Data= text;
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://www.google.com", // added comma // form action url
      data: Data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(output)
        {
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= output;
        }     
      });
}
```

Comment: What you mean? i can't get you

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors.
The JS should look like

```js
window.samepage = function()
{
    var text =document.getElementById("pv2").value;
    var Data= text;
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net", // form action url
       data: Data,
       cache: false,
       success: function(output)
       {
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= output;
       }     
    });
    return false;
}
```

1. Function to function
2. Var to var
3. Document to document
4. in url the comma is missing, and ajax GET supports only same domain.

See my sample made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/57N2n/

Comment: In your example it is loading but for me it is not workingfor me.what may be the reason problem with library file or what could be the reason

Comment: It is because when you try it is cross domain. But in my example it is same domain. Try to use some html in your local and try. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.  $.support.cors = true; is required when the source is from different location. with google url the error of Access Denied is coming. Also you need to send the data in the form of key value pair, either as query string in the url or as json object in the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        samepage();
        function samepage() {
            $.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.rediff.com/",
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(output) {
                       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
                },
                error: function(jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

    <div id="output" style="border: 1px solid; width: 1000px; height: 500px;">
    </div>
```

Comment: hi it is throwing alert box what may be the reason .it will depend on browser .it is not loading the rediff.com

Comment: This means some error is coming. You need to put break point in the error function and see the values in  jqXhr, status, errorThrown parameters.

Comment: It is showing the empty alert box .it is not showing any values

Comment: see the values of jqXhr, status.

Comment: Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: https://c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1374051684000/JqueryA/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js :: .send :: line 18"  data: no]   i am getting the alert box like this

Comment: No i have no idea of this error. The code is working fine at my end.